# Combine two rows in Dataframe using a Unique Value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I converted a list into a Dataframe and now my data looks like this.

[image: Data looks like this.]

I want to use the unique Business ID to merge two rows in this Dataframe. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `first` in a `groupby` to get first non-null value

Consider the data frame `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Bars=[np.nan, 1, 1, np.nan],
    BusID=list('AABB'),
    Nightlife=[1, np.nan, np.nan, 1]
))
df

   Bars BusID  Nightlife
0   NaN     A        1.0
1   1.0     A        NaN
2   1.0     B        NaN
3   NaN     B        1.0
```

Then

```
df.groupby('BusID', as_index=False).first()


  BusID  Bars  Nightlife
0     A   1.0        1.0
1     B   1.0        1.0
```

Comment: Beat me to it by seconds! I like using `first` better than `sum` now that I think about it, since `groupby` will end up combining the columns for you.

Comment: The solution that I wanted uses sum() because it converts the nan values to zero. What is the advantage of using the first()? Is it preserve the data type?

Comment: No, I used `first` because you said `merge`.  That is ambiguous!  I guessed as to what you meant.  My guess assumes you want to fill in the null spots with something else in that column for that group.  `first` does that.  `sum` assumes that merging means totalling up everything in that group.  That isn't what I'd describe as merging.  I'd call that aggregating.  If `sum` is what you were after.  By all means, accept @Engineero's answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just wanted to know the details of the function. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like `df.groupby('Business ID').sum()`. As an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'a': [1, 2, 3, 1],
                          'b': [5, 6, None, None],
                          'c': [None, None, 7, 8]})
df
#    a    b    c
# 0  1  5.0  NaN
# 1  2  6.0  NaN
# 2  3  NaN  7.0
# 3  1  NaN  8.0

new_df = df.groupby('a').sum()
new_df
#    b    c
# a          
# 1  5.0  8.0
# 2  6.0  0.0
# 3  0.0  7.0
```